# How to get a value out of bs4.element.Tag

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am working with `BeautifulSoup` for a web scraping project. I have a tag:

```
<span class="sal "><em class="iconRup"></em>40.0 Lacs</span>
```

and I want to retrieve `40.0 Lacs` from this.

I tried using :

```
salary = soup.find('span', class_ = 'sal')
print(salary.string())
```

but this gives a `None object` . How to do I proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<span class="sal "><em class="iconRup"></em>40.0 Lacs</span>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser").find('span', class_='sal')
print(soup.getText())
```

Output:

```
40.0 Lacs
```